# Pokemon stats calculator

Tags: c++, beginner, c++11, design-patterns, pokemon

I have a simple working (so it's not a hypothetical stub) framework for calculating Pokemon stats that will later be incorporated in a game. It uses the LCRNG from the first game in order to be as compatible as possible. I use formulas from the Bulbapedia Wiki. The example output matches the [example given here](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Individual_values#Generation_I_and_II).

Things I want to focus on:

- Does the random engine satisfy the `UniformRandomNumberGenerator` concept correctly? Can its usability be improved? I don't want to go crazy and over-engineer it.
- I'm not working on embedded system but I use `uint8_t` to make it explicit that the values have range [0, 255]. And there is some (tiny) bit manipulation as well. Or is it just better to use an `int`?
- Better way to organize my data structures. Right now I made the class an aggregate for easy initialization but that limits the usefulness of the class. I'm worried about maintainability and don't want to give the `Pokemon` class too much responsibility.
- The "extern" thing is terrible, but it's better than duplication with a "base_stats_class". Better way of handling it?

Of course, readability and other stuff are welcome criticism too.

```
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdint>
#include <random>
#include <limits>

/* Satisfies UniformRandomNumberGenerator concept */
struct PokemonRandEngine
{
    using result_type = uint32_t;
    result_type min() { return std::numeric_limits<result_type>::min(); }
    result_type max() { return std::numeric_limits<result_type>::max(); }
    result_type g() { return prand(); }

    result_type operator()()
    {
        return g();
    }

    PokemonRandEngine()
    {
        static std::random_device rd;
        seed(rd());
    }
private:
    uint32_t next = 1;

    /* Pokemon's LCRNG */
    uint32_t prand()
    {
        next = (next * 0x41C64E6D) + 0x6073;
        return next;
    }

    /* Seed prand */
    void seed(uint32_t seed)
    {
        next = seed;
    }
};

struct stats_t
{
    uint8_t hp;
    uint8_t atk;
    uint8_t def;
    uint8_t spd;
    uint8_t spc; /* special */
};

struct pokemon
{
    std::string name;
    stats_t stats;
    stats_t ivs;
    int level;

    void populate_ivs()
    {
        static std::uniform_int_distribution<int8_t> uid(0, 15);
        static PokemonRandEngine cre;
        ivs.atk = uid(cre);
        ivs.def = uid(cre);
        ivs.spd = uid(cre);
        ivs.spc = uid(cre);
        /* The HP IV is calculated by taking the least significant bit
         * of each IV and then constructing a binary string
         */
        ivs.hp = (ivs.atk & 1) | (ivs.def & 1) | (ivs.spd & 1) | (ivs.spc & 1);
    }

    uint8_t calculate_hp(uint8_t base, uint8_t iv)
    {
        return floor(
                (
                    ((base + iv) * 2
                    + floor(ceil(sqrt(0))/4)) /* Assume 0 for Effort Values for now */
                    * level
                ) / 100
            )
            + level
            + 10;
    }

    uint8_t calculate_otherstat(uint8_t base, uint8_t iv)
    {
        return floor(
                (
                    ((base + iv) * 2
                    + floor(ceil(sqrt(0))/4)) /* Assume 0 for Effort Values for now */
                    * level
                ) / 100
            )
            + 5;
    }    

    void calculate_stats()
    {
        extern std::array<pokemon, 1> base_stats_array;
        stats_t base_stats = 
            std::find_if(base_stats_array.begin(), base_stats_array.end(),
            [this] (pokemon p) { return p.name == name; })->stats;
        stats.hp = calculate_hp(base_stats.hp, ivs.hp);
        stats.atk = calculate_otherstat(base_stats.atk, ivs.atk);
        stats.def = calculate_otherstat(base_stats.def, ivs.def);
        stats.spd = calculate_otherstat(base_stats.spd, ivs.spd);
        stats.spc = calculate_otherstat(base_stats.spc, ivs.spc);
    }
};

std::array<pokemon, 1> base_stats_array = {
    { { "mewtwo", { 106, 110, 90, 130, 154 } } }
};

int main()
{
    pokemon wild;
    wild.name = "mewtwo";
    wild.level = 70;
    wild.ivs = { 4, 14, 5, 8, 6 };
    wild.calculate_stats();
    std::cout << (int)wild.stats.hp << " " << (int)wild.stats.atk << " " << (int)wild.stats.def << " " << (int)wild.stats.spd << " " <<  (int)wild.stats.spc;

    std::cout << std::endl;

    wild.ivs = { 0, 2, 6, 10, 12 };
    wild.calculate_stats();
    std::cout << (int)wild.stats.hp << " " << (int)wild.stats.atk << " " << (int)wild.stats.def << " " << (int)wild.stats.spd << " " <<  (int)wild.stats.spc;
}
```

Output:

> ```
> 234 178 138 198 229
> 228 161 139 201 237
> ```

Answer (score 7):

The first thing that strikes me is a lack of readability and consistency.

> ```
> struct stats_t
> {
>     uint8_t hp;
>     uint8_t atk;
>     uint8_t def;
>     uint8_t spd;
>     uint8_t spc; /* special */
> };
> ```

Whats does `stats_t` mean? Why not just name it `Stats`? `_t`seems to have pitfalls. See the question: [How should I mark types in C and C++ programs?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/223345/how-should-i-mark-types-in-c-and-c-programs)

Why have you capitalized some structs, but not others?
Are the variable shortened to match the game? If not, full name may be advisable.

Also, perhaps wrapping `uint8_t` into a class would make it easier to maintain.

> ```
> int main()
> {
>     pokemon wild;
>     wild.name = "mewtwo";
>     wild.level = 70;
>     wild.ivs = { 4, 14, 5, 8, 6 };
>     wild.calculate_stats();
>     std::cout << (int)wild.stats.hp << " " << (int)wild.stats.atk << " " << (int)wild.stats.def << " " << (int)wild.stats.spd << " " <<  (int)wild.stats.spc;
>
>     std::cout << std::endl;
>
>     wild.ivs = { 0, 2, 6, 10, 12 };
>     wild.calculate_stats();
>     std::cout << (int)wild.stats.hp << " " << (int)wild.stats.atk << " " << (int)wild.stats.def << " " << (int)wild.stats.spd << " " <<  (int)wild.stats.spc;
> }
> ```

In my opinion, there is way too much code in main. Separate this out into clearly named functions. This will increase readability and make maintenance easier.

> ```
> wild.ivs = { 4, 14, 5, 8, 6 };
> ```

I would also change all these numbers to named variables.

```
wild.ivs = { health, attack, strength, ... };
```

`.ivs` is also not a clear name in my opinion.

Comment: I didn't look at the randomization.

Comment: `.ivs` is very clear to me, and I feel it should be to anyone familiar to Pokemon. Each Pokemon has something called [IVs](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Individual_values) and that is what they are referred to by the technical Pokemon world. Using `ivs` is the clearest term.

Comment: Ahh, you're right. I'm not familiar with Pokemon, unfortunately.

Comment: @Justin, fair enough, but arguably people unfamiliar with the terminology might still need to maintain the code. The author should always provide a glossary of terms or list of abbreviations used in the field in such cases.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, your random number generator does seem to meet the [`UniformRandomNumberGenerator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/UniformRandomNumberGenerator) description.

Sorry that this is so negative, your code looks more like C than C++.

Instead of using C casts like `(int)` prefer `static_cast`.

> ```
> std::cout << (int)wild.stats.hp << " " << (int)wild.stats.atk << " " << (int)wild.stats.def << " " << (int)wild.stats.spd << " " <<  (int)wild.stats.spc;
> ```

Should be:

```
std::cout << static_cast<int>(wild.stats.hp) << " " << static_cast<int>(wild.stats.atk) << " " << static_cast<int>(wild.stats.def) << " " << static_cast<int>(wild.stats.spd) << " " << static_cast<int>(wild.stats.spc);
```

I would use class over struct. See: [When should you use a class vs a struct in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54585/when-should-you-use-a-class-vs-a-struct-in-c)

Your `stat_t` class should have an `<<` operator to output the various statistics.
That way the two lines in main would change to:

```
std::out << wild.stats << std::endl;
```

The names of your attributes are too short and unclear. What is `ivs`? What are the different attributes within the `stat_t` struct?

Where is the constructor for your pokemon class? The pokemon constructor should take the different parameters in main:

> ```
> int main()
> {
>     pokemon wild;
>     wild.name = "mewtwo";
>     wild.level = 70;
>     wild.ivs = { 4, 14, 5, 8, 6 };
>     wild.calculate_stats();
> }
> ```

Could look like:

```
stat_t tmpIvs(4, 14, 5, 8, 6);      // stat_t needs a constructor....
pokemon wild("mewtwo", 70, tmpIvs); // pokemon needs a constructor....
```

Answer (score 4):

The other answers already provided good feedback and I agree that you should consider better naming and be more consistent with the naming style for the classes/structs. In particular, avoid excessively abbreviated names. Just spell out things like `special`, `speed`, `attack`, etc.

Also, do use constructors to initialize your data. As it stands, you leave room for uninitialized data bugs, since some of your struct members are not default initialized.

**A few other points:**

1. I suggest using a `class` for `PokemonRandEngine`. It already has some private data and methods. The general convention is to use structs for Plain-Old-Data (POD) aggregates that have only public data and no behavior (methods).
2. The min/max methods of `PokemonRandEngine` could be `static`. They don't require access to any member state. Or at the very least, they should be marked `const`.
3. Speaking of `const` methods, take a look on when to mark methods `const`: [What is a const member function?](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness#const-member-fns)
4. The `base_stats_array` also appears that it should have been a `const`, unless you expect to change its data during runtime. I would also move its declaration to the top of the file to avoid having to redeclare `extern` references to it, which can lead to annoying linker errors if a typo is introduced in one of the declarations. Just avoid repetition when you can.
5. Check the returned iterator of [`find()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) before dereferencing it:

   > ```
   > stats_t base_stats = 
   >      std::find_if(base_stats_array.begin(), base_stats_array.end(),
   >      [this] (pokemon p) { return p.name == name; })->stats;
   > ```

   You are assuming that the function always succeeds, but if the element is not found, it will return `base_stats_array.end()`, which is not a valid iterator and cannot be dereferenced. If you're on a debug build and lucky, your compiler might trap with an assertion, or it might just crash mysteriously. Check the iterator before calling `->` on it.
6. You have this code and comment in a couple places:

   > ```
   > floor(ceil(sqrt(0))/4)) /* Assume 0 for Effort Values for now */
   > ```

   So let's instead move that "Effort" computation to a separate helper function, so in the future when it is actually replaced with some logic, you won't have to update multiple places:

   ```
   // FIXME: Assume 0 for Effort Values for now
   static double calc_effort() { return std::ceil(std::sqrt(0)); }
   ```
7. Strictly speaking, the math functions from `<cmath>` and the sized integral types from `<cstding>` belong to `namespace std`, so they should be `std::` qualified. They work without the namespace prefix on most compilers because the C and C++ header files are usually shared, so the C headers have the names defined globally. This is not a requirement though, your code might fail to compile with a more strict compiler or even in a future update of your current one. A more portable program should just use the namespace prefix.